# Porque un simbolo SF no aparece?

Tags: ios, swift

Estoy creando un tab bar en swift y estaba provando diferentes simbolos. En cuanto quiero poner un simbolo que esta separado por puntos(por ejemplo square.and.arrow.up.circle.fill), el programa no lo reconoce. Que puedo hacer?

```
enum Tab: String, CaseIterable {
case house
case plusminus
case person
case leaf
case gearshape
```

}

```
struct CustomTabBar: View {
@Binding var selectedTab: Tab
private var fillImage: String {
    selectedTab.rawValue + ".fill"
}
private var tabColor: Color {
    switch selectedTab {
    case .house:
        return .blue
    case .plusminus:
        return .black
    case .person:
        return .purple
    case .leaf:
        return .green
    case .gearshape:
        return .orange
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como sabes no funciona porque el `rawValue` aparecería algo como `squareAndArrowUpCircle` y eso no existe.

Una opción como solución es usar un `switch` para poder incluir diferentes soluciones para las excepciones.

```
enum Tab: String, CaseIterable {
    case house
    case plusminus
    case person
    case leaf
    case gearshape
    
    var fillImage: String {
        switch self {
        case .plusminus:
            //Si agregas .fill a este no existira
            return rawValue
            //Solucion especial
        case .gearshape:
            return "square.and.arrow.up.circle.fill"
        default:
            return rawValue + ".fill"
        }
    }
    var tabColor: Color {
        switch self {
        case .house:
            return .blue
        case .plusminus:
            return .black
        case .person:
            return .purple
        case .leaf:
            return .green
        case .gearshape:
            return .orange
        }
    }
}
```

o también puedes dar un valor especial al `rawValue`.

```
enum Tab: String, CaseIterable {
    case house
    case plusminus
    case person
    case leaf
    //Valor especial al rawValue
    case gearshape = "square.and.arrow.up.circle"
    
    var fillImage: String {
        switch self {
        case .plusminus:
            //Si agregas .fill a este no existira
            return rawValue
        default:
            return rawValue + ".fill"
        }
    }
    var tabColor: Color {
        switch self {
        case .house:
            return .blue
        case .plusminus:
            return .black
        case .person:
            return .purple
        case .leaf:
            return .green
        case .gearshape:
            return .orange
        }
    }
}
```

Despise puedes usarlo así.

```
struct CustomTabBar: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Tab

    var body: some View{
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            ForEach(Tab.allCases, id:\.rawValue) { tab in
                Text(tab.fillImage)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: tab.fillImage)
                    }
                    .tag(tab)
            }
        }.accentColor(selectedTab.tabColor)
    }
}
```

Puedes bajar la aplicación con todos los symbols de esta pagina de Apple.

https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/